# Loading 3 json files into neo4j database at a time in java

Tags: java, neo4j

I have 3 json files in the array s
String[] s = {"1.json","2.json","3.json"};

Now I want load all these 3 file in to neo4j database at a time
for that i used

call apoc.load.json('file:///Users//arundhathi.d//Documents//Neo4j//default.graphdb//import//1.json') yield value as person Return person

call apoc.load.json('file:///Users//arundhathi.d//Documents//Neo4j//default.graphdb//import//2.json') yield value as person Return person

call apoc.load.json('file:///Users//arundhathi.d//Documents//Neo4j//default.graphdb//import//3.json') yield value as person Return person

But I don't want to write the cypher query again and again for loading each different files.

**so that I want take file name as input and pass it to cypher query**

I tried like this

**call apoc.load.json('file:///Users//arundhathi.d//Documents//Neo4j//default.graphdb//import//s[0]') yield value as person Return person**

**according to this the 1.json file is to be taken and to be loaded but it is not taking up since s[0] is considered as string not as variable**

How can I do this ? pleae help me

Answer (score 2):

You need pass array of filename as [parameters](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/), unwind their, concatenate with path and call apoc.load.json:

```
WITH {s} as files,
 'file:///Users//arundhathi.d//Documents//Neo4j//default.graphdb//import//' as path
UNWIND files as file
call apoc.load.json(path + file) yield value as person 
Return person
```

Comment: How to take filename as array values in cypher query in neo4j. Example for the above query WITH {s} as files,
 'file:///Users//arundhathi.d//Documents//Neo4j//default.graphdb//import//' as path
UNWIND files as file
call apoc.load.json(path + file) yield value as person 
Return person                          where to mention array s values in neo4j query

Comment: @ArundhathiD Read about parameters with example: http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.1/drivers/run-statements/